Does $L_{\omega^{CK, X}_1}[X] \cap 2^{\omega} = HYP(X)$?
Are the reals in $L_{\omega^{CK, X}_1}[X]$ always equal to the reals hyperarithmetic in $X$?

Doesn't the proof that $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}\cap 2^\omega=\mathsf{HYP}$ relativize?

@NoahSchweber I don't know.  Honestly, I'm really weak on reasoning about the constructable universe and I'd love a good reference to help me get better because Sacks doesn't really touch it in Higher Recursion Theory and in the set theory books it's usually general L_\alpha rather than the hyperarithmetic stuff.

Yes, they are. Here's a proof sketch:

Let $\omega_1^{CK,X}$ be the smallest ordinal with no $X$-computable copy. I claim that the reals in $L_{\omega_1^{CK,X}}[X]$ are exactly the reals $\Delta^1_1(X)$.

One direction: suppose $A$ is a real in $L_{\omega_1^{CK,X}}[X]$. Then letting $\triangleleft$ be the standard well-order on $L_{\omega_1^{CK,X}}[X]$, there is some ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK,X}$ such that $A$ is the $\alpha$th real in the $\triangleleft$ order. This gives us a $\Delta^1_1$ definition of $A$: $n\in A$ iff some $L[X]$-hierarchy exists whose $\alpha$th element accoridng to $\triangleleft$ contains $n$, and $n\not\in A$ iff some $L[X]$-hierarchy exists whose $\alpha$th element according to $\triangleleft$ doesn't contain $n$.

The other direction: suppose I have $\Sigma^1_1(X)$ formulas $\varphi(x)\equiv\exists Y\theta(x,Y)$ and $\psi(x)\equiv\exists Y\rho(x,Y)$, with $\theta,\rho$ having only number quantifiers, such that $\{x:\varphi(x)\}=\{x: \neg\psi(x)\}=A$. For each $n$, consider the pair of trees $T_n, S_n$ whose illfoundednesses correspond to the truth of $\varphi(x), \psi(x)$ respectively. Let $U_n$ be the tree of "simultaneous descending sequences" through $T_n$ and $S_n$; basically, a node on $U_n$ of length $k$ is a pair $(a,b)$ where $a$ is a node on $T_n$ of length $k$ and $b$ is a node on $S_n$ of length $k$, and the tree ordering on $U_n$ is given by extension in both coordinates. The map $n\mapsto S_n$ is $X$-computable, so the supremum $\gamma$ of the ranks of the $S_n$s is $<\omega_1^{CK,X}$; moreover, each $S_n$ has rank that of the well-founded member of $\{T_n, S_n\}$. So now $\gamma$, or more precisely $X^{(\gamma)}$, can tell for each $x$ whether $x\in A$ or $x\not\in A$. So $A\in L_{\omega_1^{CK,X}}[X]$.



But does  $\Delta^1_1$ = HYP necessarily hold in $L_{\omega^{CK,X}_1}$?  I'm pretty sure  Harrington produced a real $a$ with $\omega^{CK,a}_1 = \omega^{CK}1$ such that $L{\omega^{CK}_1}[a]$ has $\Delta^1_1$ sets that aren't hyperarithmetic.  -- I am remembering  correctly see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118706/definition-of-hyp-in-l-omega-1cka?rq=1

Ohh that $\Delta^1_1$ formula isnt evaluated in $L_{?}[?]$ it's a true $\Delta^1_1(X)$ formula so it should be ok.
